# I want to bash script execute itself with out my end any executing

Tags: linux, bash

I want write a script that script execute itself when i update any command in the script then itself it has to check and execute

> cat script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

 date

 echo ++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 df -h

 echo +++++++++++++++++++++++++
 cat /etc/fsab

 echo +++++++++++++++++++++++++
  uptime
```

this is the example if i add any command for os information into the script then script should itself has to understand and execute their itself with out my end any executing, i know that command in bash "-nt" newer than i tried with this but not succeed

Please give some suggestions

Comment: One problem - you can't prevent the script from executing half-written updated version of itself. You would need to be very careful with editing to save only completely finished script. Otherwise (also in case of typo) the bad version would get executed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing I can image is:

Write a seocond script that checks if your script hast changed and executes it if so. Maybe save the MD5 of your script for comparison.

If you need this for development:

Use `watch` to see how the output changes.

Comment: can u please explain more with details .. pls give syntax also.. how i run the 2nd script continuously and how it knows

Comment: Why can't the old script itself check for newer version, execute self again in the background and then exit (so that only the new version will be kept running)?

Comment: @Marki555 Of course it can, but it would make things more complex.

Answer (score 1):

if you have 'inotify-tools' installed on your machine, watch for modify event on the first script from the second script and then execute it. The second script can be written as below.

```
#!/bin/bash

#  Wait for modify event
while inotifywait -e modify /first/script &/dev/null; do
    # Execute first script where we add commands
    /first/script 
done
```

Comment: You must also ensure that the old version of the 1st script is stopped when you start the new one... otherwise you would end up with all the versions running in parallel

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for my question , this is the solution

```
#!/bin/bash

dd=10
dat=`date '+%H%M'`
until [ $dd -eq 100 ]

do

sleep 1
new=`md5sum script.sh |awk '{print $1}'`
old=`md5sum scriptold.sh |awk '{print $1}'`

if [ "$old" != "$new" ]; then
./script.sh >"loglog.$dat"
cp -pr script.sh  scriptold.sh
fi
done
```

Whenever i update any thing in the script.sh , automatically the script.sh will execute from the help of main script , but this main script should run continuously :(